# Cannot reduce the size of image which is set as background image

Tags: css

I have three images set like this

[image]

html code :

```
<div class="lb-controlContainer">
<div class="lb-closeContainer">
<a class="lb-close"></a>
</div>
<div class="lb-downloadContainer" hidden="">
<a class="lb-download"></a></div><div class="lb-turnContainer" hidden="">
<a class="lb-turnLeft"></a><a class="lb-turnRight"></a>
</div>
<div class="lb-zoomContainer">
<a class="lb-zoomOut"></a>
<a class="lb-zoomIn"></a>
</div></div>
```

css

```
.lb-data .lb-zoomOut {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    background: url(data:image/png;base64,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) top right no-repeat;
    text-align: right;
    outline: none;
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=70);
    opacity: 0.7;
    transition: opacity 0.2s;
}

.lb-data .lb-close {
    display: block;
    float: right;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    background: url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABsAAAAbCAMAAAC6CgRnAAAAPFBMVEX///8AAAD9/f2CgoKAgIAAAAAAAAAAAABLS0sAAAAAAACqqqqqqqq6urpKSkpISEgAAAC7u7u5ubn////zbsMcAAAAE3RSTlMASv6rqwAWS5YMC7/AyZWVFcrJCYaKfAAAAHhJREFUeF590kkOgCAQRFEaFVGc+/53FYmbz6JqBbyQMFSYuoQuV+iTflnstI7ssLXRvMWRaEMs84e2uVckuZe6knL0hiSPObXhj6ChzoEkIolIIpKIO4joICAIeDd7QGIfCCjOKe9HEk8mnxpIAup/F31RPZP9fAG3IAyBSJe0igAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==) top right no-repeat;
    text-align: right;
    outline: none;
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=70);
    opacity: 0.7;
    transition: opacity 0.2s;
}
```

when i try to reduce the button size to  width: 10px;height: 15px;

[image]

it is displayed like this

[image]

its container values changes but image size still same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add background-size:cover to your icons.